# In Gerrit, is there a query string to list my outgoing reviews?

Tags: gerrit

In Gerrit, I would like to find all of my open changes for which I have reviewers listed. (The intent is to then go through these to remove reviewers from stale CL's.) Is there a query string that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
status:open owner:self reviewerin:MY_TEAM
```

Where MY_TEAM is the group that your team members belong to. This will show your open changes that has reviewers from your team.